# Uncaught DOMException: Error :hidden' is not a valid selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I am trying to load more items when clicked on a button load more. The code returns error: 
**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.moreArticle:hidden' is not a valid selector.**

```
        <div class="articles col-lg-10 offset-lg-2">

            <div class="article moreArticle col-lg-5">
                <h3>Workshop k tématu  spolufinancovaných projektů z ESI fondů</h3> 
                <p>28/12/2018</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article moreArticle col-lg-5" style="display: none;">
                <h3>Workshop k tématu  spolufinancovaných projektů z ESI fondů</h3> 
                <p>28/12/2018</p>
            </div>
            <div class="article moreArticle col-lg-5" style="display: none;">
                <h3>Workshop k tématu  spolufinancovaných projektů z ESI fondů</h3> 
                <p>28/12/2018</p>
            </div>

             <div id="loadMore" style="">
                <a href="#">Načíst další články</a>
             </div>

        </div>
```

And my javascript:

```
  $('#loadMore').on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.moreArticle:hidden').slice(0, 6).slideDown();
    if ($('.moreArticle:hidden').length === 0) {
      $('#loadMore').fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });
```

I run this using cash-dom in webpack. Any idea what is wrong with the code?

Comment: The error suggests you're using `:hidden` with a `querySelectorAll` call, even though it's a jQuery-only thing. The error probably comes from another part of your script.

Comment: I executed the above code in jsfiddle it works fine. The given error is not coming from this script.